# How can I bypass drf Token Authentication when using firebase for authentication in django?

Tags: django, firebase, pyrebase

I need to sign in a user using firebase from my django app.I have done what I think I needed to do but I seem to be missing something.I am using the pyrebase library.I have created a user on firebase and now I need to sign them in.
I am posting the email and password on Postman and I get the 'idToken' and 'refreshToken', which means the user gets authenticated on firebase.But this only works when I use the drf Token authentication(DEFAULT AUTH CLASSES) and authorization token of a user previously created on django admin. What am I missing so that I can authenticate the user without the drf token authentication?

views.py

```
config = {
  "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "authDomain": "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://xxxxxxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

auth = firebase.auth() 

class Auth(APIView):
   
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        email = "xxxx@gmail.com"
        password = "xxxx"
    
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

        return Response(user)
```

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so basically, you don't need any authorization in any of the authentication views. Since you have a global default of `IsAuthenticated`, you need to overwrite the `permission_classes` in the View.

```
class Auth(APIView):
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you very much.I will need to connect the users on firebase to the ones on my db.Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought pyrebase is like a full-blown auth backend for Django, but apparently that's not the case. You can do something like this: 1) `django_user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(email=email, defaults=some_other_user_data_but_not_password))`.2) Return the Token from this API so the client could authorize subsequent requests (`token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=django_user)`). You can also `.set_password` if you wish to copy it as well, however I am not sure that's the best idea.